# Difference between [look-alikes] and [confusables]

Tags: discussion, tags

I do not think a meaningful distinction can be drawn between the tags [look-alikes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/look-alikes) and [confusables](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confusables). There is no category charter for the first; the second defines *confusable* as words and phrases which are easily confused with one another, which would seem to include look-alike words (a question about *affect* and *effect* prompted me to delve into this).

> This tag is for questions about words or phrases that are easily confused with one another. This might be due to similar pronunciation. Examples are THEIR and THERE. If your question is about a word or phrase with multiple meanings consider the tag [ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiguity) instead.

There are only 11 questions tagged as [look-alikes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/look-alikes), and aside from one closed question, the last time any new questions were tagged with it was 2011. I propose it be merged into the larger and more current [confusables](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confusables).

Comment: `confusables` is `word choice`. - `look-alikes` is `word usage`. *choice* or *usage* should be exclusive; choice *must* have more than one word, and usage *only* one word.